# How way to operate on single items at an index in group in IGrouping?

Tags: c#, linq

I have simplified groupby code below, where I know there exists at most two records for each group, with each group being grouped by the value at index two in string a array.  I want to iterate through the list of keys in the IGrouping, and combine some values in each Group then add that result to a final list, but I am new to LINQ so don't exactly know how to access these first and/or second values at an index.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

each Group derived from var lines is something like this:

```
 key    string[]
----   ------------- 
123    A, stuff, stuff
123    B, stuff, stuff
```

and I want the result to be a string[] that combines elements of each group in the "final" list like:

```
string[]
-------
A, B
```

my code:

```
     var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@path).Skip(1).Select(r => r.Split('\t')).ToList();
     List<string[]> final = new List<string[]>();
     var groups = lines.GroupBy(r => r[2]);

     foreach (var pairs in groups)
     {
        // I need to combine items in each group here; maybe a for() statement would be better so I can peek ahead??
        foreach (string[] item in pairs)
        {
           string[] s = new string[] { };
           s[0] = item[0];
           s[1] = second item in group - not sure what to do here or if I am going aboout this the right way

           final.Add(s);
        }
     }
```

There's not too much support on the subject either, so I figured it may be helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like all you're missing is calling `ToList` or `ToArray` on the group:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    List<string[]> pairs = group.ToList();
    // Now you can access pairs[0] for the first item in the group,
    // pairs[1] for the second item, pairs.Count to check how many
    // items there are, or whatever.
}
```

Or you could avoid creating a list, and call `Count()`, `ElementAt()`, `ElementAtOrDefault()` etc on the group.

Now depending on what you're actually doing in the body of your nested `foreach` loop (it's not clear, and the code you've given so far won't work because you're trying to assign a value into an empty array) you may be able to get away with:

```
var final = lines.GroupBy(r => r[2])
                 .Select(g => ...)
                 .ToList()
```

where the `...` is "whatever you want to do with a group". If you can possibly do that, it would make the code a lot clearer.

With more information in the question, it looks like you want just:

```
var final = lines.GroupBy(r => r[2])
                 .Select(g => g.Select(array => array[0]).ToArray())
                 .ToList()
```

Comment: I tried your exact second solution before posting, but I was unsure how to to access the first and second results per key using LINQ, hence the confusing foreach loops.

Comment: @kmk09k: Now that you've provided more information, it's pretty easy - if you just want the first element out of each `string[]` in your group, that's a simple `Select` with a `ToArray` at the end. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks - your edited second solution worked for me.  In reality I have to write a bit more logic to combine my grouped items then in my example so I just did var final = lines.GroupBy(r => r[2]).Select(g => g.Select(a => a).ToArray()).ToList() and operated on the list.  The result was instantaneous, so I'm not complaining.